# App slow/delay if turn off developer mode

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-native

What others facing is the whole app will delay or slow when developer mode is turn off. Well, mine is contrary. My app become slow and delay when I turn off developer mode.

Whatever button I tapped, if it's onPress function dispatch with redux, it will delay 1 -2 seconds, sometimes 3 seconds. Anyone facing this issue before?

I follow the documentation on how to setup redux for log and everything.

Store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import reducers from './reducers';

const middlewares = [thunk];
if (__DEV__) {
    middlewares.push(logger);
}
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default store;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './Store.js';
import AppNavigator from './src/AppNavigator'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppNavigator />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

What could possibly goes wrong ? Your help really appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Expo (`create-react-native-app`) or baseline react native?

Comment: baseline react native

Comment: Anyway, my min SDK version is 16, if I increase it to 23 , the problem will fix?

Comment: Maybe that will help.  I am not sure.  Could the problem be in your reducers or in `<AppNavigator/>`?  I cannot see why this would be slowing things down.  If you remove logging altogether, does the app run faster?

Comment: Do you means in reducers too many data ? Button especially in FlatList quite delay. I think is update setState problem caused it slow. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe...you'll need to post  the code of your FlatList and associated reducers.  It is worth noting that when you run in dev mode with remote debugging on,   your JavaScript is running in Chrome on your computer.  It is possible that if your computer is powerful that the Javascript runs faster on the computer than on the device...especially if memory becomes an issue.  Does the slow down happen when remote debugging is off?

Comment: I increase SDK version and its did improve the speed. Almost ruin my app by updating react native version and react version. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion.